# Mongo ranking results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a collection like

```
db.books.insertMany([
  {"products" : [{"name": "name1", "ids": [4, 5, 6]}], "author" : "Dante", "shelf": "a" },
  { "products" : [{"name": "name1", "ids": [4, 5]}], "author" : "Homer", "shelf": "a" },
  { "products" : [{"name": "name1", "ids": [2]}], "author" : "Dante", "shelf": "b" },
])
```

and I want to retrieve all documents where "shelf" is 'a'
and sort by 2 conditions:
1 - by Author
2 - documents where products.ids not contains 6 should be the first.

Could anyone help?

Comment: What did you try so far?  Also: recommend you give us an example of edge conditions around "not contains 6", i.e. is the order of those docs that are "first" unimportant as long as they do not contain 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

- First `$match` the `shelf` value with "a".
- Then create an auxiliar value where will be `true` if 6 not exists into `products.ids`, otherwise false.
- Then `$sort` by values you want.
- And use `$project` to remove the auxiliar value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {"shelf": "a"}
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rank": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$products",
              "cond": {"$in": [6,"$$this.ids"]}
            }
          },[]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "rank": -1,
      "author": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {"rank": 0}
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GxGekmhJJYH)

Comment: you're a great man!!! 1 million thanxxxx!

Comment: @izum286 accept it as solution also, there is  button on the left, this will help J.F and others to know if answer is answered and if working

Comment: Um -- I think this answer does not address the `products` array having more than one element.  I tried adding more items to the playground and the sort order coming out is nondeterministic.   @izum286 : Could you please edit question to show exactly what the sort order should be when multiple `products` exist for an author?

Comment: Hi @BuzzMoschetti, can you share the playground with that values? Thanks

Comment: @J.F.   https://mongoplayground.net/p/gPwL0LglD68   But it in general, I think the OP wants finer control over author+ids sorting which means `$unwind`.

Comment: But in that example, both documents has '6' so the sort is by author name which means `Dante` is first and second `Homer` right?. Using `$unwind` you can also get the result but I tried not to use it.

Comment: Well, yes, Dante is first and Homer is second -- but what about the second part of the sort condition, to make "not 6" appear before "contains 6"?

Comment: I don't get your point, there is not any document with `6` before other without `6`. I think you mean the `products` array is not sorted? I think OP doesn't want that (and my query does not do that either).

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti 
 about the second part of the sort condition, to make "not 6" appear before "contains 6" - 
 in
"$sort": {
      "rank": -1,
      "author": 1
    }
set "rank": 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation that sorts more granularly on author+"not containing 6".

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {shelf:'a'}}
    ,{$unwind: '$products'}
    ,{$addFields: {sortMarker: {$cond: [
    {$in: [6, '$products.ids']},
        "Z",  // THEN make sortMarker at the end                                 
        "A"   // ELSE make sortMarker at the start                               
    ]}
                  }}

    ,{$sort: {'author':1, 'sortMarker':1}}
]);
```

which given this input set:

```js
{"products" : [
        {"name": "name3", "ids": [6, 7]},
        {"name": "name2", "ids": [4, 5]}
    ],
     "author" : "Homer",
     "shelf": "a" },

    {"products" : [
    {"name": "name1", "ids": [4, 5, 6]},
    {"name": "name4", "ids": [9]},
    {"name": "name7", "ids": [9,6]},
        {"name": "name7", "ids": [10]}

    ],
     "author" : "Dante",
     "shelf": "a"},

    { "products" : [
    {"name": "name1", "ids": [2]}
    ], "author" : "Dante",
      "shelf": "b"}
```

yields this result:

```js
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "products" : {
        "name" : "name4",
        "ids" : [
            9
        ]
    },
    "author" : "Dante",
    "shelf" : "a",
    "sortMarker" : "A"
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "products" : {
        "name" : "name7",
        "ids" : [
            10
        ]
    },
    "author" : "Dante",
    "shelf" : "a",
    "sortMarker" : "A"
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "products" : {
        "name" : "name1",
        "ids" : [
            4,
            5,
            6
        ]
    },
    "author" : "Dante",
    "shelf" : "a",
    "sortMarker" : "Z"
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "products" : {
        "name" : "name7",
        "ids" : [
            9,
            6
        ]
    },
    "author" : "Dante",
    "shelf" : "a",
    "sortMarker" : "Z"
}
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "products" : {
        "name" : "name2",
        "ids" : [
            4,
            5
        ]
    },
    "author" : "Homer",
    "shelf" : "a",
    "sortMarker" : "A"
}
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "products" : {
        "name" : "name3",
        "ids" : [
            6,
            7
        ]
    },
    "author" : "Homer",
    "shelf" : "a",
    "sortMarker" : "Z"
}
```

Optionally, this stage can be added after the `$sort`:

```js
    {$group: {_id: '$author', products: {$push: '$products'}}}
```

And this will bring the sorted "not containing 6 then containing 6" items together again as an array packaged by `author`; the `$push` retains the order.  Note we need only need `author` in `_id` because the match was for *one* shelf.  If more than one shelf is in the match, then we would need:

```js
    {$group: {_id: {author:'$author',shelf:'$shelf'}, products: {$push: '$products'}}}
```